# Cannot get user data in NestJs authorization

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend, nest

I don't get user in this string in roles.guard.ts     const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
user is undefined, but when i delete other code and leave only this:

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    colnsole.log(user)//user is exist
    return true
  }
}
```

and console.log i get user, idk what i should do. Code i took from documentation.

code:
roles.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();//user doesnt exist
    return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.roles?.includes(role));
  }
}

roles.enum.ts
export enum Role {
    User = 'User',
    Admin = 'Admin'
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        AuthModule,
        UserModule,
        ProductModule,
        ReviewModule,
        OrderModule,
        CategoryModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [
        AppService,
        PrismaService,
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useClass: RolesGuard
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, your `RolesGuard`, as you've set it globally, is running before whatever authentication guard you have, and as such won't be able to read whatever the authentication guard is *going* to be doing. You could, and probably should if you plan to keep the `RolesGuard` global, make the authentication guard global as well, and add some metadata to routes that you want to skip the authentication of the user for, so that it can run first and let the `RolesGuard` run second

Comment: i think the same, but i don't know how to fix it. i write like this  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)
but it's doesn't help

Comment: Because `@UseGuards()` is a local binding which happens _after_ the global one. You either need a global authentication guard, or to only use the authorization guard locally